# Plink error "Stopping as there are no SNPs left for analysis"

Tags: command-prompt, putty, plink

This is the first time I'm going to use Plink. I have downloaded the `plink.exe` and set path as given in webpages to use `plink`. And typed `plink`, which must give the summary of using Plink. But it is showing the error as

> Error: Stopping as there are no SNPs left for analysis

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different Plink's (a name coincidence):

1. the ["whole genome association analysis toolset"](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/),
2. the ["the PuTTY command-line connection tool](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html).

It looks like you have downloaded the first, but wanted the latter.